# The definition of object '[sp_name]' has changed since it was compiled on fail-over to mirror database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, failover, database-mirroring

We have two SQL 2012 database servers configured in a mirror with a witness for automatic fail-over.

Yesterday the primary server suffered a HDD degradation which triggered the fail-over, however when the secondary server became the principle we started to see many errors on execution of some SPROCs.

> The definition of object '[sp_name]' has changed since it was compiled

I understand that this can be resolved by running `sp_recompile` on the new principle, which would force a recompile on all SPROCs, functions and triggers.

This is not ideal as it requires manual intervention on fail-over. Is this a problem I can resolve through amending the configuration, or is it a known SQL Server bug?

**EDIT:**

Edition and version number -

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)  Standard Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Comment: this `The definition of object '[sp_name]' has changed since it was compiled` is not an error,its an warning,are you running administrative tasks on principal like disabling triggers ,also post exact service pack  you are running

Comment: `primary server suffered a HDD degradation which triggered the fail-over` then it will be a one time task which triggered this behaviour

Comment: There's no admin tasks running that would disable triggers. Incidentally the failing SPROCs are all `SELECT` queries, no inserts, updates or anything that would invoke a trigger. I've updated my post with the SQL edition and vr number.